# R ifelse statement based on range of values from different size datasets

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, dplyr

I have two different size datasets with start and stop times people were on two different drugs. I want to combine them so that each time from either dataset is explicitly included along with the corresponding variables for both drug use (0/1).

Example data:

```
library(dplyr)    
set.seed(100)
    df <- data.frame (id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                      start=c(0,10,16,21,0,13,21,0,6,9),
                      stop=c(9,15,20,24,12,20,25,5,8,14),
                      drugA=rbinom(10,1,0.5))

df2 <- data.frame (id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
                   start=c(12,20,2,12,17,22),
                   stop=c(18,25,8,17,19,25),
                   drugB=c(1,1,1,1,1,1))
```

`drugA`/`drugB` represents the two drugs where 1 indicates they were on the drug and 0 when they weren't. For `df2`, for any times not shown means they were not on the drug for this period e.g. id=1 was not on `drugB` for time 0-12.

The resulting dataset I want is:

```
finaldf<-structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    start = c(0L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
    16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 24L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 
    9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
    22L, 24L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
    16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 24L), stop = c(2L, 5L, 
    6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
    20L, 21L, 22L, 24L, 25L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 
    14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 24L, 25L, 2L, 
    5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
    20L, 21L, 22L, 24L, 25L), drugA = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), drugB = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("id", "start", "stop", 
"drugA", "drugB"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -57L
))
```

My attempt so far to get the overall shape of the dataset has been:

```
t<-sort(unique(c(df$start,df$stop ,df2$start,df2$stop)))  #list all the times
finaldf<-data.frame(id = rep(unique(df$id), each = length(t)))
finaldf$stop<-rep(t, each = length(finaldf))
finaldf<- finaldf %>%
          group_by(id) %>%
          mutate(start = lag(stop)) %>%
          ungroup()
finaldf<-filter(finaldf,start>=0)
```

Now I want to create the drugA and drugB variable based on the original times in the two datasets which is where I run into problems. I have tried an awkward attempt using an `ifelse` statement inside `dplyr` to do it by id but I am obviously working with different size datasets so not sure if this is the correct way to go?

```
finaldf<-finaldf  %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(drugA=ifelse(df$drugA==1 & df$start>=finaldf$start & df$stop<=finaldf$stop ,1,0),
         drugB=ifelse(df2$drugB==1 & df2$start>=finaldf$start & df2$stop<=finaldf$stop ,1,0)) %>% ungroup()
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what do you want finally? So please include your expected output.

Comment: I have given the final dataset I want above in the code, see `structure(list..` above. I want time varying variables of drugA and drugB as I am running a marginal structural model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is probably to convert everything to a simpler long-format first. Specifically, I would convert everything to have one row per unit time (i.e, an entry for state at time 1, another entry for state at time 2, etc.).

For this, I am splitting the data.frame first by id (to allow later filling for gaps) then by row (to extend each period to have an entry per unit time). Then, for each drug, I fill in any missing times (assuming they are not on the drug) using `complete` from `tidyr`. Your design here implies that every individual was in the study for the same amount of time, but you could simply redefine `allTimes` inside the `lapply` function for each individual if that is not true.

```
maxTime <- max(c(df$stop, df2$stop))

allTimes <-
  0:maxTime

allIds <-
  c(df$id, df2$id) %>%
  unique %>%
  sort

fullData <-
  lapply(allIds, function(thisID){
    tempA <-
      df %>%
      filter(id == thisID) %>%
      split(1:nrow(.)) %>%
      lapply(function(thisSet){
        data_frame(
          id = thisID
          , time = thisSet$start:thisSet$stop
          , drugA = thisSet$drugA
        )
      }) %>%
      bind_rows %>%
      complete(time = allTimes, fill = list(id = thisID, drugA = 0))

    tempB <-
      df2 %>%
      filter(id == thisID) %>%
      split(1:nrow(.)) %>%
      lapply(function(thisSet){
        data_frame(
          id = thisID
          , time = thisSet$start:thisSet$stop
          , drugB = thisSet$drugB
        )
      }) %>%
      bind_rows %>%
      complete(time = allTimes, fill = list(id = thisID, drugB = 0))

    out <-
      left_join(tempA, tempB)
  }) %>%
  bind_rows
```

This code gives a snapshot throughout the data:

```
fullData %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(c(1,5,10,15))
```

returns:

```
    time    id drugA drugB
   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0     1     0     0
 2     4     1     0     0
 3     9     1     0     0
 4    14     1     0     1
 5     0     2     0     0
 6     4     2     0     1
 7     9     2     0     0
 8    14     2     0     1
 9     0     3     0     0
10     4     3     0     0
11     9     3     0     0
12    14     3     0     0
```

My guess is that this long form may actually work better for whatever next steps you have planned (because you can treat each day separately, e.g. to graph participant states (here with ggplot2)

```
fullData %>%
  mutate(drugState = paste(drugA, drugB, sep = "-")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time
             , y = id
             , fill = drugState)) +
  geom_tile(height = 0.9) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(4, "Set1")[c(3,1,2,4)] )
```

[image]

However, if you really want to get back the start-stop format you had, you can identify the point at which the drug-state changes, then summarise for that period for each individual:

```
reformatted <-
  fullData %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    drugChange =
      (drugA != lag(drugA, default = -1)) |
      (drugB != lag(drugB, default = -1))
    , period = cumsum(drugChange)
  ) %>%
  select(-drugChange) %>%
  group_by(id, period, drugA, drugB) %>%
  summarise(start = min(time)
            , stop = max(time)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Which returns:

```
      id period drugA drugB start  stop
   <dbl>  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1      1     0     0     0    11
 2     1      2     0     1    12    15
 3     1      3     1     1    16    18
 4     1      4     1     0    19    19
 5     1      5     1     1    20    20
 6     1      6     0     1    21    25
 7     2      1     0     0     0     1
 8     2      2     0     1     2     8
 9     2      3     0     0     9    11
10     2      4     0     1    12    17
11     2      5     0     0    18    20
12     2      6     1     0    21    25
13     3      1     0     0     0     5
14     3      2     1     0     6     8
15     3      3     0     0     9    16
16     3      4     0     1    17    19
17     3      5     0     0    20    21
18     3      6     0     1    22    25
```

Comment: Great thank you! I actually want the start, stop format for a time-varying analysis.

Comment: Glad it works for you. Does this get you all the way to what you need? If so, consider accepting the answer to let others know that it solves your issue ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers ). If not, let me know what it is lacking and it may be easy for me to extend the answer a bit.

Comment: It does perfectly, I was just waiting to see was there another solution, maybe a base R type solution using ifelse statements before accepting an answer. Perhaps there is a more efficient approach (current run time approx. 25mins), although I understand any approach will take time as we are creating a large dataset. If there isn't one, I will accept yours! Thanks again.